# Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25

Tags: java, smtp

I am trying to send an Email for forgotpassword by using SMTP.But i am getting an exception like below

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
```

The below is the java code

```
    String to = email;


            String from = "XXXXXXX@gmail.com";          
            String host = "localhost";
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();    
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);         
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            try {
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);             
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                        to));
                message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
                message.setContent("<h1>This is actual message</h1>", "text/html");
                Transport.send(message);
}
```

Can any one please tell me how can i send an email using SMTP

Comment: Is your SMTP host accessible?

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server running on localhost'?

Comment: Please print the full stack trace.

Comment: Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926125/smtp-client-java-program

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to connect to gmail . if its the case, don't use localhost host, use one of mx records of gmail.com.

Comment: Now i changed localhost to properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); now i am getting class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 pc9sm4679803pdb.6 - gsmtp....Is it mandatory to provide credentials of from mail